# Тип или имя пространства имен не существует /asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

VS'2015
Есть решение, в нем два проекта - Domain (различные библиотеки) и Web(контроллеры, представления).
Пытаюсь в Domain использовать класс из Web, выдает ошибку, что не может найти такое пространство имен.
Все решение изначально писалось на .net 4.5, т.е. ошибок с версиями быть не может.
Вставить ссылку на Web не могу - циклическая зависимость.
Интересная особенность: одну папку из Web он все же видит, но не нужную мне.
То есть настроить видимость вроде как возможно. Вопрос в том, как?

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз появляется циклическая зависимость, значит налицо архитектурная ошибка. Правильным решением является вынос общего кода в 3-ю библиотеку и выставление зависимостей первых двух проектов от неё. Либо же, вынос этого функционала в Domain

Comment: Да, так возможно сделать.
Но меня смущает другое: что одну директорию в Web он каким-то магическим образом видит, а ту, которая нужна мне, нет (по идее ведь  данный класс тоже можно перенести в видимую область).
Почему так? Где это можно настроить?

Comment: @A_Mergasov, я не знаю, как там он у Вас папку видит. Но можно добавить элемент из другого проекта в этот проект: для этого нужно «Add existing item» сделать и там нажать «Add as link». Но это ужасный подход.